# IntelliJ IDEA does not detect Angular components functions used in component html

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, ide

I am working on an Angular 2 application and use IntelliJ IDEA for development. I like the feature of showing unused variables. However, if a function is used in component HTML, the component typescript files still say the function is unused. Is there any configuration to avoid this? It is very frustrating as I don't like to see unused variables or functions and if I accidentally delete them, they are not detectable until run time since this is JS.

**Update 2017-06-05T14:04:00Z**:

IDE Version: IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.4 Build #IU-171.4694.23, built on June 6, 2017 Mac OS X 10.12.3

Public function in Angular component

```
backToEdit(): void {
    this.finished = false;
}
```

Usage in Angular component HTML

```
<button type="button" (click)="backToEdit()" class="btn btn-default stepy-finish">
    <i class="position-left icon-arrow-left13"></i>Back to Edit
</button>
```

Comment: what IDEA version do you work with? Is the function public or private? what does its usage look like? Please provide code snippets that show what function declaration and usage look like

Comment: @lena updated version and usage.

Comment: works fine for me using provided example. Please try invalidating caches (File | Invalidate caches, restart) - does the problem persist? Do you have AngularJS plugin installed and enabled?

Comment: The issue I reported is for Angular 2. I still have the problem.

Comment: Checked my answer? @TechCrunch

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs when using Angular2 or AngularJS and it will be fixed for both versions by installing [Angularjs](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6971-angularjs) plugin.

A quote from the plugin page:

> Support for AngularJS and Angular

It's name is a little confusing but it works ;)